# FEM Stiffness and Mass matrices for 2d cubic trial functions

Tags: finite-element

I want to use FEM to solve a 2D eigenvalue problem for the biharmonic equation

\begin{align}
&K \psi= \lambda M \psi\\
&\psi=\nabla \psi\cdot \hat{n}=0\quad \text{on boundaries}
\end{align}

where $K$ is the stiffness matrix corresponding to

$$K_{ij} = \int_{A} \nabla^2 \psi_i  \nabla^2 \psi_j \mathrm{d}A$$

and $M$ is the mass matrix

$$M_{ij} = \int_{A} \psi_i \psi_j \mathrm{d}A$$

Because the equation is fourth order I am using cubic trial functions, both height and slope.

I know how to get the stiffness and mass matrices in 1D, but I am stumped by the 2d problem.

Does anyone know of a suitable reference?

Comment: What is the problem that you are having in 2D? Have you read any reference on how to implement FEM for this kind of equation? For example, [this](http://www.colorado.edu/engineering/CAS/courses.d/AFEM.d/Home.html).

Comment: @nicoguaro Thanks so much for your answer and the edit to my note.  Parenthically, how do I insert equations into a question?  My OP was about where to find a reference and you have answered that. I will read through and see if I can find what I am looking for, namely how to express K_{ij} and M_{ij} for 2d cubic trial functions.

Comment: Are you solving it in a squared domain? Please be accurate presenting your problem in order to simplify the answer. Thank you

Comment: To use equations in the questions you can use LaTeX syntax, click edit to check it out.

Comment: @HBR I am ashamed to say I don't know what a squared domain refers to.  The shape of the region I want to work in is variable (rectangular, circle) but it doesnt sound like what you are asking.  I was hoping to use triangular elements, since that has worked so well for my 2nd order problems, but perhaps I should use something else.  I need to come clean and say that these are my first steps with a fourth order problem.

Comment: Specifically, on the page @nicoguaro linked to there is a section entitled "Thin plates...". The referenced document, http://www.colorado.edu/engineering/CAS/courses.d/AFEM.d/AFEM.Ch23.d/AFEM.Ch23.pdf discusses how to implement a triangular element of this type. Some of the other documents in that section provide needed background.

Comment: Cubic trial functions are not enough -- you need to use functions that are also continuously differentiable in 1d, such as cubic splines.

Comment: I have recently returned to this problem and found, following @Wolfgang Bangerth's comment and the notes in Strang and Fix, that in a square domain 2d test functions that are the product of  1d cubic test functions work quite well. In an arbitrary 2d geometry, reduced quintic test functions (Cowper, Lindberg and Olson, 1970, Intl J. Solids Structures) work equally well. In both cases, the number of degrees of freedom>1, so the computations require vectorization for more than trivial domains.  I have both octave/matlab and fortran versions available, if anyone is interested